# How would you convert a decimal into binary?

Tags: binary, scheme

Other than defining values to decimals such as 2 = 10, does anyone know of a way in scheme to create a procedure that converts a number into binary? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Depending upon what you need, there is a built-in procedure `(number->string z radix)` that will convert a number to a string, allowing you to specify the numeric base. For example, to convert `22` (decimal) to `10` (binary):

```
huski> (number->string 22 2)
"10110"
```

Just to be clear, you would specify 2 as the second parameter since binary is base-2.